# Calculating specs of the Li-Ion battery depending on Robot's weight

Tags: batteries, measurement, cost

I want to build a moving wireless robot. Vehicle needs to have a speed of 50 kms/hr and needs to have a tracks instead of wheels. The approximate weight (without the batteries) might range between 20 - 27 kilograms. Also, I need some thing like the raspberry pi on board the buggy to do some calculations and use a camera on board.

Given such vague specs, I need to have atleast a ballpark figure of the amount of power I will be needing and the amount of batteries I will need to use. The way I am going to develop this thing is over a couple of years and working from the simplest module to the biggest and most complex. Thus, the chassis, tracks, servo that drives the tracks, and the complete battery management system will come at the later stages of the development, but I need to have that ball park figure for budgetary purposes.

UPDATE:

I need a range of 1000 - 1200 meters

Comment: No mention of runtime? Propelling ~30kgs at 50kph on tracks is not a small job, you'll be looking at a lot of battery power which will add a lot of weight which will need more battery power to move...

Comment: Yeah, tracks are very inefficient, especially at high speed. This is why tanks have huge diesel or gas turbine engines.

Comment: @JohnU Sorry, I have updated the question. I need a range of 1200 meters

Comment: Meters are not a measure of time last I looked. How many minutes/hours/days/years must this machine work before the battery is recharged / changed? Or how much distance must it travel in total (just 1200 meters, or round 1200 meters 100 times). Is it driving on flat smooth tarmac, through mud, up hills?

Comment: @JohnU A single `operation cycle` will be 8 hours to 16 hours. (24 hours will be very impressive if taking it from 16 to 24 hours does not add a significant cost over head). 1200 meters in all. Terrain is definitely not smooth. Device has to climb at least small hills comfortably and many times. Mud can be expected. about one feet of water can be expected.

Comment: @JohnU It is a bot that will enter a zone, scan the area, stay there for some time (may be even power down for some time). Send back images to a server, loiter a little more .. finally come back. That's the function of it. along with some more specific jobs that can be ignored right now.

Comment: @JohnU It also needs to `remember` where it was sent yesterday and go the same way today or the next 1000 times (as long as it was charged every day) without any other human intervention. This was also the main reason I wanted to put tracks since they are more stable in a more varied class of terrain including a river basin, a hill, a desert, a rainforest.

Comment: No matter what you do, replaying a route by just turning the wheels/tracks/legs the same amount is not a good idea, especially if the route may be soft, slippery, or have changes like debris appearing/moving. Counting turns of the wheels/tracks is __helpful__ for this, but you will probably need more than that. Look up the stuff used in the DARPA Grand Challenge. Remembering = saving = your software should have no problem saving the info to a file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compute the power source you need to know the maximal and average power consumption of your robot and the maximal working time between the recharges.

In order to estimate the motor power (everything else will consume a lower power) you will need the maximal acceleration of your robot and how often it will need to accelerate/decelerate.

Then multiply the working time by the average power and you will get the capacity of the batteries in W.h

On my estimation, you will need at least 1kW motor and if you want to work 2h, then 2kW.h batteries you will need. If the batteries are 48V then 42A.h capacity you will need. The current draw of the motor will be around 20A on maximal power mode. The acceleration time from 0 to 50km/h will be something like 10s

The efficiency of your mechanics is not calculated here.

#### Addendum that changes almost everything:

After reading the parameters added in the question, I think such robot can not be designed to work from batteries. For 24h work of 1..2kW motor, your batteries will get huge.

Better consider using internal combustion engine. The power density of the fuel is the best from the existing energy sources. The ICE will provide enough power for the electronics as well.

If you want to use the electrical motors in order to get better control, you can use a hybrid schematic - a small battery that to power the robot for 1..2h and small diesel or gasoline engine that to charge the batteries from time to time.

Comment: Might be on the low side even. As a point of reference: an upright bicycle requires about 450W electrical to go 45km/h and that has very efficient propulsion. I'd reckon tracks are much more than twice as inefficient. Also, another important consideration is the required acceleration - if that needs to be quick (especially at higher speeds) you may want to overdimension quite a bit more.

Comment: @user36129 - I don't know what is the efficiency of the tracks. That is why, I didn't include it in the estimation. Notice as well, that the time 0..50km/h is as low as 10s. The bicycle probably accelerated slower.